# Find transformations for two non-square matrices $A$ and $B$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, tensors, permutation

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$:

[image]

What transformation needs to be applied to transform matrix $A$ into matrix $B$?

```
A = {{0, c, b, -c + b c, a c, -a + a b, c + b c, a c, a + a b}, {0, c,
    b, c + b c, a c, a + a b, -c + b c, a c, -a + a b}, {0, -1, 0, b, 
   a, 0, b, a, 0}}

B = {{0, c, b, 0, c, b, 0, -1, 0}, {-c + b c, a c, -a + a b, c + b c, 
    a c, a + a b, b, a, 0}, {c + b c, a c, a + a b, -c + b c, 
    a c, -a + a b, b, a, 0}};
```

**EDIT:**

I found one method that only uses $\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, and the result is the same as direct differentiation $\frac{dQ^T}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$. The disadvantage of this method is the need to glue the matrix again. Maybe I can get around this with some kind of unified tensor operation ? To immediately receive the entire matrix, without additional gluing.

```
Rx = RotationMatrix[\[Phi][t], {1, 0, 0}];

Ry = RotationMatrix[\[Xi][t], {0, 1, 0}];

Rz = RotationMatrix[\[Psi][t], {0, 0, 1}];

Q = Rz.Ry.Rx;

v = {\[Phi][t], \[Xi][t], \[Psi][t]};

T1 = Flatten /@ D[Q, {v}];

T2 = Flatten /@ D[Transpose[Q], {v}];

P1 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

A1 = T1.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
      0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

A2 = T1.{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};

A3 = T1.{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

Transpose[P1.ArrayFlatten[{{A1}, {A2}, {A3}}]] == 
   Flatten /@ D[Transpose[Q], {v}] // MatrixForm;
```

Comment: `LinearSolve[A, B]`?

Comment: @LukasLang please, form your comment as answer

Comment: @LukasLang looking at the matrices I have an assumption about permutation matrices, am I right? if so, what will they look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
B == ArrayReshape[Transpose[ArrayReshape[A, {3, 3, 3}]], {3, 9}]
```

> True

Also, in loop style:

```
result = ConstantArray[0, {3, 9}];
Do[
  result[[i, 3 (j - 1) + k]] = A[[j, 3 (i - 1) + k]], 
  {i, 1, 3}, 
  {j, 1, 3}, 
  {k, 1, 3}
];
result == B
```

> True

Or with a permutation matrix of size $27 \times 27$:

```
P = Block[{A, B, a},
   A = Array[a, {3, 9}];
   B = ArrayReshape[Transpose[ArrayReshape[A, {3, 3, 3}]], {3, 9}];
   SparseArray[D[Flatten[B], {Flatten[A], 1}]]
   ];

ArrayReshape[P.Flatten[A], Dimensions[B]]
```

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to formalize your proposed operation? Express it as a formula? As I assumed, you are using a permutation.

Comment: Well, if you treat both matrices as 3-tensors `ArrayReshape[A, {3, 3, 3}]` and `ArrayReshape[B, {3, 3, 3}]`, then it is just about permuting the first two slots of the tensors.

Comment: I mean the following. Find such a matrix $X$, or a pair of matrix $x$ and $X$ for example (I don't know exactly how many are needed), so that either $AX=B$ or $xAX=B$.

Comment: Hm. You certainly cannot do that if you require that both `x` and `X` are permutation matrices; this can be seen when you compare the two columns in `A` and `B` that contain the `-1`.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4201431/656085 Please see the very end of the answer. I need something similar, but I don't know the structure of the $P_{9\times9}$ and $P_{3\times3}$ matrices.

Comment: While trying to do something myself, you have already suggested another option :)). Yes, you have correctly caught the path. Those. there must be a permutation matrix consisting of zeros and ones (or several matrices) that transform A into B using some formula.

Comment: Not sure what you need this for. Is it about coding? Just in case that you mean to code that in C, C++ or whatever: note that dense matrices and arrays are stored in flattened form. So the permutation matrix `P` from my post, applied to the raw buffer of `A` would do what you want.

Comment: I work with high-dimensional equations of motion that include non-stationary moments of inertia. There are a large number of matrix and vector operations. To keep things simple, I use tensor, vector, and matrix calculus. As for the option you proposed, this is what I need. Only as far as possible, it is necessary to exclude operations of flattening, etc. Check out the link to the topic that I attached in the comment.

Comment: See my edit please. I found a variant of the way how to switch to the transposed matrix through the original one.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) to find one possible matrix such that `A.X==B`:

```
X = LinearSolve[A, B];
A.X == B // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

Comment: The result is a matrix $X$?

Comment: @dtn Yes, `X` is a 9x9 matrix. If you are looking for another kind of "transformation", you'll have to be a bit more specific with your requirements. (When talking about transformations in the context of matrixes, the usual thing that's meant is a transformation matrix such as the `X` from the answer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you are talking about. At the moment, for my tasks there is only one requirement that transformations lie in the class of vector-matrix operations. But I will happily explore possible alternatives if you point me to the sources.

Comment: Is it possible using this method to obtain a permutation matrix (or several objects), which would include zeros and ones? Like a normal permutation matrix?

Comment: I don't think this can be done purely using permutation matrices and dot products. You need to allow some other operations for this to be possible

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201386/formula-for-the-transition-from-tensors-to-vectors-in-matrix-calculus/4201431#4201431 Please see the very end of the answer. I need something similar, but I don't know the structure of the $P_{9×9}$ and $P_{3×3}$ matrices.

Comment: @dtn As far as I can tell, no such permutation matrices exist (assuming a permutation matrix is a matrix where each row/column has exactly one `1` and the rest is `0`). A matrix product with such a matrix can only ever permute rows/columns, but that is not sufficient to perform the permutation you are after.

Comment: See my edit please. I found a variant of the way how to switch to the transposed matrix through the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `Part`

```
Flatten[A[[All, # ;; ;; 3]] & /@ Range@3 // Transpose, 1] // Transpose
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4201431/656085 Please see the very end of the answer. I need something similar, but I don't know the structure of the $P_{9\times9}$ and $P_{3\times3}$ matrices.

Comment: See my edit please. I found a variant of the way how to switch to the transposed matrix through the original one.